# Reading different xml elements from socket continously and mapping it to DTO classes generated from XSD - Java

Tags: java, xml-parsing, stream, jaxb, dto

I want to map different XML elements to proper DTO generated from XSD files (which are generated from RNG schemas). These XMLs must be read from socket and the data arrives continously. Server is never closing the stream and I am not recieving any sign, that a new element is now arriving. The elements on stream are complete - the next appears, when other is already sent.

This is a part of data, which I am reading from socket:

```
<element1 prop1="value">
    <otherTag foo="baaaaaar"/>
</element2>
<otherElement prop3="value" prop4="value">
    <otherTag3 foo="baaaaaar">
           <aaa bbb="ccc1"/>
           <aaa bbb="ccc2"/>
           <aaa bbb="ccc3"/>
    </otherTag3>
</otherElement>
...and other emelents...
```

I tried to parse it with StaX (i count START_ELEMENT and END_ELEMENT events to determine if I recieved the whole element), build string and then send it to JAXB to map it. I realised that, it is not a good way, because it doubles parsing (StaX and then JAXB). Anyway I have to specify a class to wchich JAXB have to map recieved XML element.

How to do it with 'better way'?

Comment: Why exactly was StAX not good? I think what you describe is a primer case for StAX or SAX and JAXB over it. I'd definitely go with JAXB over StAX.

Comment: StAX does not provide methods to get the whole XML element. I do not want to build the XML string from scratch with StAX API.